# Trying to convert CSV file contents to a desired format using python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to convert CSV file contents from format A to Format B. I tried pandas, default dict, Dict writer, etc but I could not make it out.The problem is that it is printing horizontally but not vertically. Please find the example below.[image]

Format A:

item            meas     COL A       COL B       COL C       COL D

84P37W265B3      B1       3970      99.82368    99.82368    0.07556675

84P37W265B3      B3       3960      95.10101

84P37W265B3      B5       3705      96.89609    96.89609    0.05398111

84P37W265B3      B6       3763      98.45868    98.45868    0.02657454

84P3XT135A4      B1       7904      99.73431    99.73431    0.02

84P3XT135A4      B3       7817      97.5694     100         0.01

Format B:

item    84P37W265B3 84P3XT135A4

meas     B1         B1

COL A   3970    7904

COL B   99.82368    99.73431

COL C   99.82368    99.73431

COL D   0.07556675  0.02

meas    B3          B3

COL A   3960        7817

COL B   95.10101    97.5694

COL C   -           100

COL D   -           0.01

meas    B5 -

COL A   3705 -

COL B   96.89609 -

COL C   96.89609 -

COL D   0.05398111 -

meas    B6 -

COL A   3763 -

COL B   98.45868 -

COL C   98.45868 -

COL D   0.02657454 -

Can anyone help me out in this, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can use python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

> here is the working code for conversion of Format A to Format B

```
import csv

a_csv = r'D:\A.csv'
b_csv = r'D:\B.csv'

#  Read Format A CSV Format
with open(a_csv) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    item_list = []
    item_list.insert(0, 'Item')
    meas_list = []
    meas_list.insert(0, 'meas')
    cola_list = []
    cola_list.insert(0, 'COL A')
    colb_list = []
    colb_list.insert(0, 'COL B')
    colc_list = []
    colc_list.insert(0, 'COL C')
    cold_list = []
    cold_list.insert(0, 'COL D')
    for row in reader:
        item_list.append(row['item'])
        meas_list.append(row['meas'])
        cola_list.append(row['COL A'])
        colb_list.append(row['COL B'])
        colc_list.append(row['COL C'])
        cold_list.append(row['COL D'])

#  Write Format B CSV Format
with open(b_csv, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(item_list)
    writer.writerow(meas_list)
    writer.writerow(cola_list)
    writer.writerow(colb_list)
    writer.writerow(colc_list)
    writer.writerow(cold_list)
```

check output:

```
Item    84P37W265B3 84P37W265B3 84P37W265B3 84P37W265B3 84P3XT135A4

meas    B1  B3  B5  B6  B3 

COL A   3970    3960    3705    3763    7817

COL B   99.82368    95.10101    96.89609    98.45868    97.5694

COL C   99.82368        96.89609    98.45868    100

COL D   0.07556675      0.05398111  0.02657454  0.01
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the output file is having only the last row value "84P3XT135A4 B3 7817 97.5694 100 0.01"  for all item.

Comment: check my output in answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the output is corresponding last row value, it is leaving the previous row values. In the output, it is not having below values.

84P37W265B3 B1 3970 99.82368 99.82368 0.07556675

84P37W265B3 B3 3960 95.10101

84P37W265B3 B5 3705 96.89609 96.89609 0.05398111

84P37W265B3 B6 3763 98.45868 98.45868 0.02657454

84P3XT135A4 B1 7904 99.73431 99.73431 0.02

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, it is working. This is static, how to handle if it is dynamic. I mean we do not know the numbers of columns in the input csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank @cyclops for the reply. Please find my code for the dynamic type .i.e. the user do not know number of columns in the input csv file.

CODE:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

column_header=[]

columns = defaultdict(list) 
with open('C:\outfile4.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
  for row in reader: 
        for (k,v) in row.items(): 
            columns[k].append(v)


b_csv = r'C:\outfile5.csv'

with open(b_csv, 'w') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',   quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for key,values in sorted(columns.iteritems()):
      if key == 'item':
         writer.writerow([key]+values)
    for key,values in sorted(columns.iteritems()):
      if key == 'meas':
         writer.writerow([key]+values)
    for key,values in sorted(columns.iteritems()):
      if key != 'item' and key != 'meas':
         writer.writerow([key]+values)
```

It is working but please let me is any other simple way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cyclops: I hope, I am not assigning anything except 'item' and 'meas'. So I meant dynamic, sry if have assumed wrongly.  This is done because I need the item as column header. Is it possible to have B1 below B3 below B5 below B6 for an item as shown in Format B?